# Author name hyphen(-) not recognized in Elsevier's CAS Latex template

Tags: elsarticle, author, els-cas

I'm using Elsevier's CAS Latex Double-Column Template LaTeX package. (https://ko.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk)

There was a problem that I couldn't solve while writing the paper, so I posted this to ask experts for help.

(1) the title is marked with a hyphen.
However,(2) the hyphen is not recognized in the author name next to the responding author email located at the bottom left of the first page, and (3) the hyphen is not applied to the reference.

Example)
(1) Gil-Dong Hong
(2) G. Hong (not recognized)
(3) Hong, G.D. (not recognized)

Is there a solution?

(1) [image]

(2) [image]

(3) [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

%% removal ORCID
\renewcommand{\printorcid}{}  

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

% Short title
\shorttitle{}

% Short author
\shortauthors{G.-D. Hong et~al.}

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{This is title}                      

\author[1]{Gil-Dong Hong}
\cormark[1]

% Email id of the first author
\ead{gd_hong@korea.ac.kr}


% Corresponding author text
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}


% Here goes the abstract
\begin{abstract}
This template 

\end{abstract}


% Keywords
% Each keyword is seperated by \sep
\begin{keywords}

\end{keywords}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\cite{example}

%% Loading bibliography style file
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{cas-refs}

\end{document}
```

[Add cas-refs.bib]

@ARTICLE{example,
author  = {G.-D. Hong},
title   = {This is title},
journal = {Journal},
volume  = {1},
year    = {2022},
pages   = {1-10}
}

Comment: You're much more likely to get help with something like this if you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code we can test and tinker with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It was difficult to explain by uploading the code, so I added a link related to the template.

Comment: @ParkShinRn The `cas-dc.cls` class is in TeX Live, so you just need to show an example document as short as it can show the issue.

Comment: @egreg As you said, I uploaded the example code.

Comment: I see (1) and (2) in the output of the sample code, but where is (3)? Do you need to add a citation (and bib file) to see it?

Comment: @frabjous Yes, that's right. I also added citation (and bib file) below the example code. Please check by adding cas-refs.bib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, their document class and stylesheet are not set up well to handle a name like that. The "correct" way to handle this is probably to take it up with the journal, but if you just need quick and dirty fixes, the following seems to help:

For (2), redefine the command `\eadauthor` which is usually derived from the `\author` command, i.e.,

```
\author[1]{Gil-Dong Hong}
\renewcommand{\eadauthor}{G.-D. Hong}
```

And for (3), put this awkward monstrosity in the `.bib` file:

```
@ARTICLE{example, 
    author = {Hong, {\mbox{G.-D}}.}, 
    title = {This is title}, 
    journal = {Journal}, 
    volume = {1}, 
    year = {2022}, 
    pages = {1--10} 
}
```

It wouldn't surprise me if there are more elegant solutions, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem. I'm satisfied with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by adding the following code in the preamble.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \eadauthor {} 
    { 
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_stm_au_seq 
        { 
            \regex_extract_once:nnNTF {(\w)\w*-(\w)} { ##1 } \l_stm_au_fn_seq
            { 
                \seq_pop_left:NN \l_stm_au_fn_seq \temp_var
                \seq_use:Nn \l_stm_au_fn_seq { .- }
                { . } 
            }
            { 
                \regex_match:nnTF { \. } { ##1 } 
                { ##1 }
                { \tl_head:n {##1}. }
            }
      }{ ~\l_stm_au_sn_seq }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```